# Is there a word for tremendous happiness coupled with relief?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a single word that would describe the feeling of say, getting a happy ending at the end of a tragic movie—like 'glad', but stronger. Feels like it exists but I just can't recall it—but if it doesn't, is there a better way to describe it other than what I put in the title?

Comment: How about *gratifying*?

Comment: ^ This. Or simply satisfactory. Although the latter doesn't emphasize 'tremendous happiness'. Instead maybe you could say that you're awfully satisfied!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> […] the feeling of say, getting a happy ending at the end of a tragic movie--like 'glad', but stronger.

This feeling is called *[catharsis](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/catharsis)*.

I don't think there's a word that fits into the same syntactic slot as *glad*, though. (There exists an adjective *cathartic*, but it's used to describe the experience — the thing that causes or triggers the catharsis — rather than the person.)

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. Could you also quote the text and source explicitly. Links have a habit of becoming invalid. Here's the recommended format https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing  Thanks.

Comment: It would be good if you gave an appropriate dictionary definition of _catharsis_, which I believe to be by far the single best answer available. I've looked, and some definitions are more appropriate here than others.

Comment: Catharsis does not seem to me to be 100% appropriate to the example given. Catharsis describes a "peace caused by relief or release" rather than implying any overwhelming happiness. I rather think that the OP is looking for a word describing the sudden transition from sorrow to happiness.

Answer (score 1):

[**Euphoric**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphoric) comes to mind.

> marked by a feeling of great happiness and excitement : characterized by, based on, or producing euphoria

I feel the word brings a "cleansing joy" aspect with it.

Comment: You should include a dictionary definition of the chosen word.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to a  [blessing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/blessing?q=blessing%20):

> - A beneficial thing for which one is grateful; something that brings well-being:
>
>   - *it’s a blessing we’re alive*

[Blessed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/blessed?q=blessed%20):

> - Bringing pleasure or relief as a welcome contrast to what one has previously experienced.

(ODO)

Answer (score 0):

The word that comes to mind is 'joy':

> Intense and especially ecstatic or exultant happiness, or an instance of such feeling.

[joy. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved November 3 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/joy.]

'Joy', however, does not denote relief; rather it denotes enormous satisfaction and contentment. In this way, 'joy' is properly esthetic: it is a static emotion. As James Joyce expresses it in his "Paris Notebook",

> ... joy is excited by whatever is substantial or accidental [Yale MS. adds after "accidental", "general or fortuitous"] in human fortunes ...

(From *James Joyce: The Critical Writings*, edited by Ellsworth Mason and Richard Ellman, Viking, 1959.)

Later in the same paragraph, Joyce adds that

> ... even tragic art may be said to participate in the nature of comic art so far as the possession of a work of tragic art (a tragedy) excites in us the feeling of joy. ... All art, again, is static for the feelings of terror and pity on the one hand and joy on the other hand are feelings which arrest us.

(op. cit.)

In a note on the text of the latter passage, the editors point out that "Joyce substitutes stasis for catharsis. That joy may result from tragedy as well as from comedy does not follow well from what he has said. In the *Portrait* he confines the discussion almost completely to tragedy and changes 'joy' to 'the luminous silent stasis of aesthetic pleasure.'"

Aside from quibbles about whether the emotion occasioned by tragedy is, properly, joy, or rather the unadorned "stasis of aesthetic pleasure" (an overwrought expression more suited to the developing character of Stephen Dedalus in *A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Man*), it is the stasis of contentment or satisfaction that constitutes such relief as may be felt in the apprehension of tragedy.

Answer (score 0):

Is ***[jubilation (also, jubilance)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=SpHY8ylWtZkC&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=jubilance+%22happy+ending%22&source=bl&ots=0FRGjIVJnP&sig=fG8L_r6o7y1EBwjEbbmWc3yHIgY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwBGoVChMI-p-thv3zyAIVg9oaCh0SVwB8#v=onepage&q=jubilance%20%22happy%20ending%22&f=false)*** what you're after?

> jubilation: a feeling of or the expression of joy or exultation
>   [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jubilation)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[gratification](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gratification)* (the noun form of the adjective *gratifying* in @Mamta D's prior comment)

> Pleasure, especially when gained from the satisfaction of a desire

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 0):

re·demp·tion
[rəˈdem(p)SH(ə)n]
NOUN
the action of saving or being saved from sin, error, or evil:
"God's plans for the redemption of his world"

Comment: You should include the source of this definition.

Comment: I realize the potential feeling coupled with being saved from evil is close to the description of the OP, but can you explain how this word relays "tremendous happiness"?